# Access multiple gRPC services each one running on separated port

Tags: go, grpc, mux

I am running a grpc server listening on localhost:9000, with 2 separate grpc services:

- AuthenticationServiceServer port:9001
- JobsServiceServer port 9002

This works correctly when I am only running the Auth server, but when adding Jobs server I get:

`"error": "rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service pb.AuthService"`

The server looks like this when working fine

```golang
var (
    port     int
    authAddr string
)

func init() {
    flag.IntVar(&port, "port", 9000, "api service port")
    flag.StringVar(&authAddr, "auth_addr", "localhost:9001", "authenticaton service address")
    flag.Parse()
}

func main() {
    log.Print("starting main service")
    conn, err := grpc.Dial(authAddr, grpc.WithInsecure())
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    authSvcClient := pb.NewAuthServiceClient(conn)
    authHandlers := resthandlers.NewAuthHandlers(authSvcClient)
    authRoutes := routes.NewAuthRoutes(authHandlers)

    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    routes.Install(router, authRoutes)

    log.Printf("API service running on [::]:%d\n", port)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port), routes.WithCORS(router)))

}
```

On some other attempts I got this error.

`"error": "rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: missing address""\`

here's the code which returned an error

```golang
var (
    port     int
    authAddr string
    jobAddr  string
)

func init() {
    flag.IntVar(&port, "port", 9000, "api service port")
    flag.StringVar(&authAddr, "auth_addr", "localhost:9001", "authenticaton service address")
    flag.StringVar(&jobAddr, "job_addr", "localhost:9002", "job service address")
    flag.Parse()
}

func main() {
    log.Print("starting main service")
    conn, err := grpc.Dial(authAddr, grpc.WithInsecure())
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    jobConn, err := grpc.Dial(jobAddr, grpc.WithInsecure())
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    defer jobConn.Close()

    jobSvcClient := pb.NewJobPostingServiceClient(jobConn)
    jobHandlers := resthandlers.NewJobPostingHandlers(jobSvcClient)
    jobRoutes := routes.NewJobPostingRoutes(jobHandlers)

    authSvcClient := pb.NewAuthServiceClient(conn)
    authHandlers := resthandlers.NewAuthHandlers(authSvcClient)
    authRoutes := routes.NewAuthRoutes(authHandlers)

    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    routes.Install(router, authRoutes)
    routes.Install(router, jobRoutes)

    log.Printf("API service running on [::]:%d\n", port)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port), routes.WithCORS(router)))
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code that is not working. What you have shown us is only attempting to connect on port `9001`; I'd expect to see another `grpc.Dial` if you are connecting to multiple services (regardless of whether they are on different hosts or different ports on the same host).

Comment: thank you for the edit, I have added the code which resulted in the error

Comment: Are you able to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I cant see any issues with the code you have pasted but this is not actually making any gRPC requests (just setting up the connections). Note that I'm assuming you are not specifying any command line parameters (so the defaults are used).